# complex permission system for sails.js / angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, permissions, sails.js

I plan to build a few apps with `sailsjs` and `angularjs`

I need help to find a solution to set flexible permissions. It means that I can manage permissions on models (CRUD) and model-functions. It should also be possible to limit access to objects in models (e.g. User can modify only customer in USA but can also read customer in Europe / user has no right to see the address from customer). Does anyone know an existing solution for that?

Or can you give me a hint how to implement an own complex permission system?

Thank you for help, Nick.

Answer (score 1):

Policies seem to be what you are looking for. http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/policies

You can use them to protect resources, and fundamentally they are just middleware, so you can use Passport.js etc.

For the angular side, I would use a global Http Interceptor, to handle the non-200 responses returned by Sails

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
- http://blog.thesparktree.com/post/75952317665/angularjs-interceptors-globally-handle-401-and-other